# How can use BETWEEN in sqlite via db.query

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've a query on sqlite that use "between" and I want to use it on standard Query.
my code is here:

```
        String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "question_group", "question_number", "is_answered"};
        String selection = "question_group = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(category)};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String orderBy = null;
        String limit = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUESTION, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```

I want to Add another condition that is :question_number between 1 and 10. I can now write this query in a single statement but I want to use it as above I told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) describing the `selection` parameter of the query() method:

> A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

If you want the following `WHERE` clause in your query

```
 WHERE question_group = :category AND question_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

then you can use the following `selection` and `selectionArgs`:

```
String selection = "question_group = ? AND question_number BETWEEN ? AND ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ String.valueOf(category), "1", "10"};
```